# Consolidação de dados em excel de uma aba de planilha para outra [Dúvida de VBA]

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macro, google-sheets

Bom dia a todos,

Recentemente tenho tentado praticar VBA com alguns exercícios práticos e me deparei com a seguinte situação na qual estou em um certo impasse.

Preciso "ler" a Sheet1 e passar todos os dados que tem listados nela para a Sheet4, no entanto, em alguns casos existem espaçamentos de linhas entre as séries de informações. Isso está me deixando confuso quanto a lógica a ser adotada.

Segue aqui as fotos das disposições da planilha e minha tentativa de código.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Macro:

```
    Sub list_vencimentos()

linha = 4
coluna = 1

linha_print = 6
coluna_print = 1

    While Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(linha, coluna) <= Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(linha, 17)
    
    If linha <= 225 Then
    
    Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(linha_print, coluna_print) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(linha, coluna)
    
    coluna = coluna + 1
    
    coluna_print = coluna_print + 1
    
    If coluna > 17 Then
    
    coluna = coluna - 17
    
    coluna_print = coluna_print - 17
    
    linha = linha + 1
    
    linha_print = linha_print + 1
    
    End If
    
    End If

Wend


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

O mais importante é exatamente você tentar e ajustar o código.

Eu usaria uma abordagem diferente, um FOR da linha início até a linha fim.
Como identificar a linha fim? Simples:

```
Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
```

Mas se seu While está funcionando direitinho, você só precisa não considerar as linhas em branco, basta encapsular ele em um IF:

```
IF cells(linha, 1).value <> "" then
```

Isso vai dizer que você só vai processar a linha em questão com seu código se o valor da primeira coluna não for vazio (o que faz sentido pra sua tabela de exemplo)